# Purpose of Generated Kotlin declarations from TypeScript definition

Tags: android, typescript, kotlin

I have generated Kotlin declarations files from Typescript npm module using `ts2kt` library. But I am not understanding the exact purpose of this conversion and how I should use the converted code in my kotlin project.

Can anyone please help me with below questions

1. If there is a npm library and I convert it to kotlin using `ts2kt`, is it converting the whole library to kotlin where I can use the same functionality?
2. How can I use the converted kotlin code in my project. All I see in the converted files is external interfaces.
3. How can I use these generated files in my android project?

Answer (score 1):

The external interfaces are all that `ts2kt` generates.  The purpose of these interfaces is to give you more type safety when you work with `dynamic` variables in Kotlin-JS.  The idea is that the JavaScript / TypeScript library you are using in your front end code is going to be called or consumed by your Kotlin-JS code.  There's an [example](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/javascript/working-with-javascript.html) in Kotlin's documentation that boils down to:

1. Run `ts2kt -d path/to/the-library's.d.ts`
2. Use the generated interfaces in your Kotlin-JS code (`theLibrary.someMethod()`)
3. Include the actual library in your JS bundle at runtime (by including it in the HTML via a script tag or by bundling everything together with the bundler of your choice).

Comment: Thank you for responding to my question. Is it possible to use the generated files in my android project? When I add the generated files in my android project, I get a lot of errors and unresolved identifiers.